# Display biography post for today's birthday person

Tags: php, wp-query

I am new in the WordPress Theme development, i am building a website using WordPress that is specially for biographies posts. I have one section called "Today's birthday", in this section i wanted to show biographies of persons who are born today's date. for example: if today's date is 11th of may, i want to show biographies posts, who are born on 11th of may ...

Will anyone help me please, as i am new, i have no idea how to write query for this task. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in a Q&A format. Please describe what you have done so far and what your specific coding issue is in completing this task.

Answer (score -1):

Well there is no Generic solution for your problem/query as WordPress is not Specifically made Biography directory.

Solution will depend on the approach you have followed.

Have you created `Custom User Role` and add biography user under that user role **`OR`** Have you created `Custom Post Type` for Biography and add posts under that ?

If its User then you must be storing Date of Birth of `User` in `user_meta` table **`OR`** if its Custom Post Type then you must be storing Date of Birth in `post_meta` table.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an actual answer